# how to run a query in c# windows form application without sql connection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to attach my database to my server at the start of my application
so stil i don't have any connection to server
i should run this code at first

```
CREATE DATABASE LibraryDB ON 
(FILENAME = 'E:\++Projects\Visual Studio 2017\Library\Library\bin\Debug\LibraryDB.mdf'),
(FILENAME = 'E:\++Projects\Visual Studio 2017\Library\Library\bin\Debug\LibraryDB_log.ldf')
FOR ATTACH;
```

How can I run this code or this query in my program?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Your SQL heavily implies you're using SQL Server, not MySQL.

Comment: You have to connect to the server in order to run ddl statements.

Comment: but i am installing sql server express in my customer PC and i want to when my program is installing in his pc the database get attached to his server

Comment: Right...so you connect to sql express on their machine. I would suggest using backup and restore instead of attaching though.

Comment: Ok but how connect to that server without managment studio

Comment: `SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection ("Server=<Name of the server>;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");` or `SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection ("Server=<Name of the server>;Integrated security=SSPI");` doesn't work?

Comment: no i got this error "A network-related o instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server  "

Comment: We can't debug this remotely for you. We have no code and we can't see your screen.

Comment: Do you have SQL Server Express installed before installing your app?

Comment: yes i have the SQL server express but i think it is just a server and not include a managing place

Comment: how can i send my Source to you?

Answer (score 0):

Just connect to the master database?

`SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection ("Server=<Your Server>;Integrated security=SSPI;database=master");`

Comment: but i dont have the database in my server attached to make a connection

Comment: You're not connecting to your database. You're connecting to the `master` database.

Comment: but i stil got that problem